# Why tablesorter.js trowing error?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

As of now i am able to sort the records using tablesorter.But why i am getting below error.i am sure i didn't change anything .

Unhandled exception at line 275, column 4 in /Public/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property '$table': object is null or undefined

Please let me know.

Comment: Which version of tablesorter do you use? And have you tested it with other browsers?

Comment: TableSorter 2.15.13  .suddenly i got an issue without changing anything.

Comment: in mozilla it's working fine...

Comment: [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: @user3494837 then you should probably report the bug.

Comment: There shouldn't be an error on that line, did you modify the file at all?